# Float input maintain width

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to css but I've got a input that I am trying to float beside dynamically generated tags but it keeps knocking it down a level.

If I change the css to float left then the input field shrinks down. I'm sure this is something simple that I am just missing being new to css.

Decent chunk of stuff, css and html are parts that matter, so here is a fiddle and excerpt that I believe is the culprit.

```
#to-address ul li, #from-address ul li {
list-style-type: none;
width: auto;
float: left;
/* ^^^ remove this line =>full size bar, tag acts as block level element */}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LDRM3/)

Thanks.

EDIT1:
To clarify, because I kind of left it out, the goal is to have a input bar where the user can click any where in the bar, why it needs to fill the width. It should allow the user to continue typing beside the newly created tag. The `float: left;` line allows it to stay inline with the tags but overrides the `width: 100%` effect that allows the user to click any where to start typing.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your `width:auto` to `width:100%`

```
 #to-address ul li, #from-address ul li {
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 100%;  //this will make your lists width 100%
 float: left;
 }
```

EDIT: if you need to keep the input on the top then you will need to change your JS code a bit

```
$(this).parent().after('<li class="tag-address" name="' + value + '">' + value + '<span class="tag-delete">&times;</span></li>');
```

Change the `.before` to `.after`

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LDRM3/13/)**

Comment: If you do that then the input gets knocked down to the next line.

Comment: @Hunter Edited my answer after your comment. Check if that helps you

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `width: auto;` to `width: 100%`